# .Net Simple Data File usage

Tags: c#, database

I've created a new project in .Net (2010 4.0) and added an SDF data file.  I've generated a dataset and created a table in it (and I believe generated the Fill and other methods).

In code, I'm trying to add a row to the database.

```
        eBureauScrubber.App_Data.matchingtempDataSet ds = new App_Data.matchingtempDataSet();
        eBureauScrubber.App_Data.matchingtempDataSet.ctfFileRow row = ds.ctfFile.NewctfFileRow();
        row.Address = "123 Main St.";
        row.City = "Overland Park";
        row.FirstName = "Matt";
        row.LastName = "Dawdy";
        row.rownum = 1;
```

EDIT: Added the next bit of code.

```
        ds.ctfFile.Rows.Add(row);
        ds.ctfFile.AcceptChanges();
        ds.AcceptChanges();

        eBureauScrubber.App_Data.matchingtempDataSetTableAdapters.ctfFileTableAdapter ctfa = new App_Data.matchingtempDataSetTableAdapters.ctfFileTableAdapter();
        ctfa.Update(ds.ctfFile);
```

This runs fine.  However, after the program completes, the data is not persisted in the database.  What am I missing?

EDIT: I've tried all different combinations of AcceptChanges() on the datatable, the dataset, running update() before, after, etc.  I'm missing something huge here.  I'm not even sure it is connecting to the "right" database.  Maybe that's my problem.

EDIT 2:  Here's what I did to get this to work (it's still funky, though).

1. Change the properties of my DB file in App_Data to "Do Not Copy"
2. Manually copy that db file to bin\debug\app_data
3. Use the data adapter's fill method to fill the ds.ctfFile data table.
4. Create a row (.NewctfFileRow())
5. Set values on that row.
6. ds.ctfFile.Rows.Add(row)
7. ds.ctfFile.AcceptChanges();
8. ds.AcceptChanges();
9. Call the adapater's update method.

Now, the data is in my database file (in bin\debug\app_data), but I can't see it because the Data Sources connection.  I'm still trying to find out how to do that.

Comment: Doesn't AcceptChanges updates it in-memory only? You'd need to call the adapter's Update method for db update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have generated a `TableAdapter` class with a `.Update()` method that you have to call to save data in your database. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for some examples.

Comment: It did.  I wasn't using it right. First, it was always copying a new copy of the database.  Somewhere.  Then I had to manually copy the database to the bin\debug\app_data folder.  Then I had to fill the dataset with the adapter, then it actually inserted.  Only reason I know that is that it was trying to insert a duplicate key, so really, I now have a database in my app_code folder that is just, well, a template I guess, and the Data Sources explorer can connect to it but doesn't show data.  I have another db that DOES have data, but I don't know how to view it except during code execution.